# How to send/receive file from device to device using java socket programming in android?

Tags: java, android, sockets, p2p

I want to make  P2P connection between two android devices and transfer files like zip, images, videos. As P2P connection between two computers no need any intermediate server to transfer files between it i want to make an android app that no need any server or web service support to transfer file between two android devices. I have search over net for it i found about java socket programming, but i don't have any idea about java socket programming nor i have work with it ever. So please tell me some thing about my concept first of all is it possible, if yes how ? any example or links will much helpful to me. thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Without help of server transfer over the internet is highly difficult. In some network it is not possible. only thing is you can transfer file to other device in LAN.

Comment: isn't possible with java socket programming ?

Comment: you cant establish socket between two device easily, If you try in LAN it seems to be easy but for internet in involves lot of technique to overcome those problems. But without Server is not possible. At least for establishing connection between to device there is need of Intermediate server